# int and ++new goes up by 2 every time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, int

Just a silly question:
I have a simple counter, but it seems that it gives the double value of what I expect.

```
short int *new = 0;
++new;
NSLog(@"Items: %hi", new);
```

And this returns:

> Items: 2

Relatively new to Cocoa, and still working out the little details as is clear form above...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't have an integer variable, you have a **pointer** to an integer variable (a short integer, to be specific).  It increments by 2 because short integers are two bytes long. A pointer variable holds a **memory address** of another value.  Incrementing a pointer means, "make this pointer point to the *next* thing in memory", where "thing" is the type of value the pointer was declared to point at.  A pointer to `double` would increment by 8 each time.

The "*" in the declaration makes it a pointer. If you just want an int, you'd just write

```
short int new = 0;
++new;
```

Comment: One thing that strikes me is that the variable is called "new".  Is that not a reserved word in Objective C?  I guess not.

Comment: No, why would it be? Objective-C doesn’t reserve any keywords beyond those in C (although `id`, `Class` and `self` have special semantics in particular contexts).

Comment: Oh I don't know; claiming "new" seems to be a fairly popular thing for language designers to do :-)

Comment: As I stated, it was a stupid thing, as it is almost all pointers in Objective-C I just automatically put in the *. Thanks a million, I will be aware of it more and it might solve some other strange behaviors when I get across it in the future.

Comment: Don't make it a habit though, in case you ever have to write Objective-C++.

Answer (score 3):

Aah, when you increment a pointer, in increments it by the *size* of the object it holds. You're looking at an address, not a number.

do this, and see:

```
short int *new = 0;
NSLog(@"Items now: %hi", new);
++new;
NSLog(@"Items then: %hi", new);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the way you define `new` is as a pointer to an integer, `*new`. You set the memory location to contain a `short int`, which is a 16-bit integer, so it takes up two bytes in memory. So increasing that on the second line means increasing the memory location by 2.

I don't think you intend to deal with memory locations. It's kind of odd to define an integer and also control its location in memory, unless in specific situations. Code that would do what you want is:

```
short int new = 0;
++new;
NSLog(@"Items: %hi", new);
```